# How safe is WebCryptoAPI these days?

Tags: web-browser, web-service

The [1Password Tool (software)](https://1password.com/) [introduced the 1Password for Teams](https://blog.agilebits.com/2015/11/03/introducing-1password-for-teams/).

I thought this is a great piece of Software, but now they can show Passwords in the Browser.

They do say:

> We encrypt everything on the client and do not have a copy of your
>   encryption keys.

and they use [WebCryptoAPI](https://www.w3.org/TR/WebCryptoAPI/) to do so. Has anyone an idea if this can really be safe?

Comment: It _can_. Yet, the WebCrypto API is still under development and this might influence the existing implementations as the API evolves to it's final state. The implementations are the realm of the browser vendors, so it's not quite sure how and what happens with browser updates.

Comment: @SmokeDispenser thank you, that's a good point. Still wondering which data will be transmitted from server to browser and if there is something like the SSL technique with public/private key pairs in browser or how they handle that part to keep a value encrypted and secure..

Comment: Basically, the document you linked specifies an API such that a website can use different crypto, carried out by the browser. That is expected to be carried out securely. Have you tried to google _"how does the browser crypto api work"_ and read some writeups on the topic?

Comment: @SmokeDispenser yes I've done a short research, dind't read all the API. Now what I've found was mostly almost 2-3 years old. Of course I could and should do a more in depth research on the topic.

Comment: "safe" in what way?

Comment: @schroeder safe in the way like what data will be transferred from client to server and from server to client. What can WebCryptoAPI use which is safe like SSL private/public keys technique. I mean I don't see how they can make an encryption safe without private/public key pairs in a browser.

Comment: So, your question *really* is, "how can encryption be secure if not SSL in a browser?"

Comment: @schroeder yes. Further more: Does the decryption really happen on my client/browser, so anyone sniffing the traffic will not have a chance do decrypt my secret passwords?

Comment: I think you need to completely re-write this question, then.

Comment: @schroeder thanks for your comment. I don't know how I should rewrite it to make it a better question. Kind of, the question could also be as simple as "Does the WebCryptoAPI uses private/public keys like SSL or SSH?" Maybe the question is just way to broad, cause at the moment I don't know enough to ask better and should just dig trough the docs, learn and know more to make it a better and more specific question.

Answer (score 2):

How secure this is depends on the implementation.

Keys can be stored as WebCryptoAPI key objects and stored locally in an IndexedDB. These can then be used to encrypt and decrypt data without the server needing the key. You can even mark keys as unextractable - this means the underlying key can never be exported (ignoring of dev tools built into the browser).

Browser storage is segregated using scheme (http/https etc.), port (443 for https) and domain. So if keys are stored from a page served via https://1password.com they can then only be accessed by pages served from that domain.

However there is a caveat. 1Password need access to the encrypted data (to serve it to you if you login elsewhere). If a malicious party can control either your DNS system of the 1password.com site they would be able to serve you a page which pulls down the encrypted passwords, decrypts them using the key object and then reuploads them to a malicious server. This means at any point in the future 1Password could obtain your passwords.

Further to this the ability to share vaults makes me sceptical that keys would be marked as unextractable. It is technically possible but a system that securely shares the vault key would be far simpler to implement.

In short if you trust 1Password this should be safer than the passwords being sent in plaintext to the server. However it still relies on trusting 1Password.

One further note. Their site states -

> even allow teammates to log in to sites without being able to see the passwords.

I would be surprised if this is done in a way that wouldn't allow a sufficiently technical teammate to extract the password in plaintext. I can't think of a way to do it that wouldn't A. not work reliably accross all sites and B. require either trusting a 1Password server with the password in plaintext or requiring your PC to be always connected.